# Write a code to convert excel data to json data

Tags: javascript, json, excel

Can you please tell me how to convert data stored in excel sheet manually into Json data using javascript code??
Consider a excel sheet name: task.xlsx and 
Path:C:\rex\task.xlsx
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

First you don't want to parse the xlsx sheet that will be a huge pain.  It will be much easier to export to a csv, then convert the csv to JSON.  Here is a similar question parsing csv into hashes.

[Parsing CSV to Array of Hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700113/parsing-csv-to-array-of-hashes)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this package from NPM that can parse XLSX file (like task.xlsx) https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel